# Anyone familiar with transfer issues?

Tags: wire-transfer, transfer, rights-issue

9 Ocober made 1000€ transfer from my Business account to My Wise Bussiness account.
Money never arrived . Their answer is They can not locate the money I have even sent a Bank Statement stamped and signed from the sender bank that the transfer was completed and never got back to the account till 08 December.Should I open dispute trough Financial Client Defense Authority?

Comment: Country? What does your bank say after talking directly to their bank?  And have you checked that My Wise Business, whatever it's supposed to be, is not a scam?

Comment: @keshlam: I imagine op is talking about a [Wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_(company)) Business account.  Wise (formerly transferwise) was founded in 2011.  While maybe he's unknowingly working with scammers, Wise itself is not a scam.

Comment: Ok Context helps.